# Purpose of nested archives

Tags: static-libraries, unix-ar

`ar` can create an `.a` file which includes another `.a` file, such that the output of `ar -t whatever.a` looks like:

```
someotherarchive.a
foo.o
bar.o
```

However, if this archive is then linked, the symbols from an `.o` in `someotherarchive.a` will not be accessible by `foo.o`.  This can be resolved by flattening with the `T` switch to `ar` when creating, but that also creates a *thin* archive.  Since there does not seem to be a flatten-but-don't-thin option, it's necessary to extract from `someotherarchive.a` first and then link the `.o`s independently to create something that contains:

```
otherarchivememberA.o
otherarchivememberB.o
foo.o
bar.o
```

Raising the question, if putting one `.a` inside another `.a` makes it inaccessible, what's the purpose of doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably this is because `ar` [was historically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_%28Unix%29) a general purpose archiving tool, like `tar`.

In other words, there is no purpose to inaccessibly nesting archives if you are creating static libraries.